Ubuntu 24.10 doesn't recognize my wifi card (Linux Mint does however)
I use the TP Link Archer TX20E card for wifi and Bluetooth on my desktop PC. I tried out Linux Mint and Ubuntu on an USB drive to choose between them and decided on Ubuntu, however in the live system, Linux Mint already recognized my wifi card. Ubuntu didn't (Bluetooth works however).
I already found this repository with drivers https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89, but sadly can't build them as I can't install make without an internet connection (and I don't have the option for a LAN cable to my PC in my apartment).
I already read on Reddit that people say the Realtek 8852AE should be supported by Kernel 5.16> or something like that and the current version of Ubuntu is way more recent than that. Why can't Ubuntu recognize it while Linux Mint can? Is it a current bug?

Edit: I tried booting up an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and it detected both wifi and bluetooth perfectly. Is there any bug prohibiting this in 24.10?

In 24.10 you could run this in terminal and see what happens sudo dmesg | grep rtw
